# If a wormhole connects between ground and sky, does an object require extra energy to pass through it?

Tags: energy, wormholes

As we know, if we bring an object from ground to sky (higher position) by normal methods, extra energy is required to overcome the gravitational potential energy.

Then if a wormhole connects between ground and sky, does extra energy also require to overcome the gravitational potential energy if an object passes through it? If so, when, and how would the extra energy is supplied? (eg: Does extra force required to push the object pass through the wormhole? Or the object loss mass to overcome the potential energy?)

Comment: We can't know what a wormhole would do. None have ever been seen.

Comment: See also [How would you connect a destination to a wormhole from your starting point to travel through it?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109649/how-does-conservation-work-in-wormholes). The trouble is that GR doesn't tell us about the global topology.