# How long would it take to build a wormhole?

Tags: speed-of-light, wormholes

If it were possible to build wormholes, would the process of building them also be faster than light as seen outside the wormhole, or would it take at least as much time as it would light to traverse that space? Say point A and point B are 500 lightyears apart, the space between them would have to be warped to build a wormhole. Would the warping of that space take 500 years, or can space be warped faster than light, seeing as it can expand faster than light?

Essentially, if we started building a wormhole to bridge 500 lightyears, would we have to wait 500 years before it was finished?

Comment: This cannot be answered because there is no way we know of to build a wormhole that connects two points in space. We know several wormhole geometries (involving exotic matter) but not how to create a wormhole connecting two chosen points. See [How would you connect a destination to a wormhole from your starting point to travel through it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109591/how-would-you-connect-a-destination-to-a-wormhole-from-your-starting-point-to-tr) for more on this.